# cpp-Construct an anonymous object

Tags: c++

I'm doing the Exercise 10.29 in c++ Primer.

> Write a program using stream iterators to read a text file into a vector of strings.

My code is this:

```cpp
#include<iterator>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int
main()
{
    // does not work
    istream_iterator<string> iter(ifstream("./test.txt")) ,eof;
    vector<string> vec(iter, eof);
    ostream_iterator<string> out(cout);
    for (auto i : vec) cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

the error is:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::istream_iteratorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char >::istream_type&' {aka 'std::basic_istream&'} to an rvalue of type 'std::basic_istream'

but when i construct an object of iftream separately,it will be ok.

```cpp
int
main()
{
    ifstream ifs("./test.txt");
    // ok
    istream_iterator<string> iter(ifs) ,eof;
```

Comment: This is expected behavior, C++ prefers to use const references for temporaties. So it will use the const& constructor from the iterator. You can't change the iterator to accept an rvalue reference (&&) so your first solution is probably the most simple one.

Comment: If you look at [`std::istream_iterator`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator), it's (3) overload (which is the one you're using), accepts the stream by lvalue reference but `ifstream("./test.txt")` is rvalue so a lvalue reference can't bind to that, which is why you get an error in the first case.

Comment: thinks, i get it!

Answer (score 0):

In the first version the `std::istream` object will be temporary, and will be destructed as soon as the `iter` variable definition is done.

Also part of the issue is that stream object can't be copied, so the iterator will save a non-constant lvalue reference to the stream.

And as for the error itself: Temporary objects can be bound by non-constant lvalue reference.

That's why one normally create an instance of the stream, and use temporary object of the iterators instead:

```
std::ifstream input("./test.txt");
std::vector<string> vec(std::istream_iterator<string>(input),
                        std::istream_iterator<string>());
```